# Access Runtime error 2448

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the following code on an OnCurrent Event in a subform:

```
    Private Sub Form_Current()
Me.Parent![QUOT_TOTAL] = DSum(" Q_SUB ", "DSUM_Q_SUB")
Me.Parent![QUOT_TOTAL].Requery
Me.Parent![QUOT_DISC] = (Me.Parent![QUOT_TOTAL] * Me.Parent![DISCOUNT_PERCENT]) / -100
Me.Parent![QUOT_DISC].Requery
End Sub
```

As soon as I open the form I get error 2448 cannot assign a value to this object. When I close the warning the form works OK.

The OnCurrent event is assigned to the subform of a parent form and the fields I want to update (as shown above) [QUOT_TOTAL] and [QUOT_DISC] are on the parent form. They are found as columns on a table but I want the form to update these as soon as changes on the subform occur.

Kindly help

thanks

Elton

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Why do you need to persist calculations in the first place, and in a manner that doesn't take account of whether the source data has actually changed? The `Requery` calls also look pointless given you are assigning a static value immediately beforehand. What do you think they are doing...?

Comment: Hi.Maybe this is due to my inexperience. To put it simple I have three fields on the form all linked to a table: QTY, PRICE and TOTAL. What I am after is that when I enter a number under QTY and PRICE the field TOTAL works QTY*PRICE or calls a query with a DSUM and stores this value in the table under column TOTAL. Do you think this makes sense or shall I keep calculations only on the form and then run queries/reports to get the Totals?

Comment: Is the TOTAL value *always* QTY x PRICE or is that just the default value? If the former I wouldn't store it at all (i.e., I'd remove the field from the table), and assign the text box's Control Source property the expression `=QTY*PRICE`; if however that calculation is just the default value that could be overridden, keep the field and assign `=QTY*PRICE` to the control's Default Value property.

Comment: Many thanks Chris - this was what I was after

Comment: OK, I'll add it as an actual answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of `QUOT_TOTAL`, if its value should *always* be `QTY` x `PRICE` I wouldn't store it at all (i.e., I'd remove the field from the table), and assign the text box's Control Source property the expression `=QTY * PRICE`; if however that calculation is just the default value that could be overridden, keep the field and assign `=QTY * PRICE` to the control's Default Value property. You can do something similar for `QUOT_DISC` with the expression `=DISCOUNT_PERCENT / -100 * QTY * PRICE`. That said, the use of the subform might still upset this...